# Как cгенерировать KeyEvent для двух кнопок?

Tags: java, android, события, клавиатура

Как cгенерировать KeyEvent для двух кнопок ? То есть чтоб сгенерировалась комбинация двух кнопок, например Alt и G.

Пробую ниже указанными методами, но не получается:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("KeyEvent","event= "+event);
        if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
            switch (event.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F10:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN:
                {
                    new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G | KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT);
                    return false;

                }

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F9:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_RED:{
                    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H | KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT));
                    return false;
                }

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F11:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_YELLOW:{
                    simulateKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT & KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y);
                    return false;
                }

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F12:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_BLUE:{
                    simulateKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT | KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }



public static void simulateKey( final int KeyCode) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                }
            }

        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: Так как генерировать, или как регистрировать ? Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я сам не очень разбираюсь, но нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку пульта, например Вверх, система поняла бы нажатие комбинации кнопок, например ALT и B.

Comment: Т.е., как я понимаю, Вам просто по какому-то событию (которое Вы сами как-то будете хэндлить) нужно сгенерить нажатие клавиш, да ?

Comment: Да, да, так и есть, нужно сгенерировать нажатие ( event )

Comment: pomojete ??????

Comment: Запостил ответ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В конце концов решил проблему. Оказалось всё было очень просто.

```
KeyEvent  newEvent = new KeyEvent(event.getDownTime(), event.getEventTime(), KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G, event.getRepeatCount(),KeyEvent.META_ALT_RIGHT_ON | KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON, event.getDeviceId(), 0, event.getFlags());
                newEvent.dispatch(this);
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(newEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Т.к. Вам нужна комбинация клавиш, то, думаю, что Вы должны передать код B с маской `META_ALT_ON`. Думаю, как-то так.

UPD: `META_ALT_ON | KEYCODE_B`

Comment: Благодарен, сейчас посмотрю и дам знать.

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит, прошу поподробнее описать что конкретно делает данный код. Просто я новенький в данной сфере :) заранее спасибо

Comment: Как я понял из инструкции, sendKeyDownUpSync() -  отправляет одновременно KeyUp и KeyDown ( то есть нажатие и отпускание кнопки ) в активное окно.

Comment: Имитирует нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре, Вы передаете код баттона - он имитирует его нажатие. Звучит банально - но, что есть. И что Вы просили )

Comment: По идее должно было быть так - зажали ```Cntrl```, зажали ```B```, отпустили ```B```, отпустили ```Cntrl```. Здесь Вы передаете ```KeyCode``` уже с "контролом", используя ```META_ALT_ON | KEYCODE_B```.

Comment: @SalutAmigo, так и не дождался от Вас ответа - у Вас получилось ?

Comment: Прошу прощения за задержку с ответом

Comment: Попробовал как Вы и сказали, но не получилось :( 
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN:{
simulateKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP);
return false;
}

Comment: то есть даже и при нажатии одной клавиши не сработало

Comment: @SalutAmigo, а что в отладчике видите ?

Comment: в метод simulateKey передается правильный KeyCode, но не понимаю почему не работает

Comment: @SalutAmigo, понял. А вот эти две строчки кода  ```Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);``` отрабатывают нормально, exception не выбрасывается ?

Comment: Да, всё нормально, без каких либо exception

Comment: @SalutAmigo, попробуйте вот [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967178/how-to-generate-key-presses-programmatically-android) метод тогда, с учетом первого ответа, который там есть.

Comment: Благодарен за помощь, сейчас попробую

Comment: Прошу прощения, уже наверное надоел, но как понимаю проблема у меня в Alt. То есть она не нажимается:  simulateKey(KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON | KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G);

Comment: Может знаете какой то метод как сделать так чтоб клавиша Alt по дефолту была нажата. То есть чтоб при нажатии другой клавиши в ее metastate была 1.

Comment: @SalutAmigo, попробуйте еще флаги META_ALT_LEFT_ON, META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, META_ALT_MASK. Может с одним из них сработает.

Comment: ne, ne poluchaetsya... :(